# Weekly event manager code not working in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have create a weekly event manager in javascript . but something went wrong. the code is not working . Please someone solve the fault.Whats wrong in it ?????

```
var plan=prompt("Hello , Made a week plan. Type the week name to add a event");
var week = ["saturday" , "sunday" , "monday" , "tuesday"];
var saturday;
var sunday;
var monday;
var tuesday;

if( plan == "saturday" ) {

var saturday=prompt("What will you do in saturday?");

} else if ( plan == "sunday") {

var sunday=prompt("What will you do in sunday?");

} else if (plan == "monday") {

var monday=prompt("var getknow=prompt(""What will you do in monday?");

} else if (plan == "tuesday" ) {

var tuesday=prompt("What will you do in tuesday?");

} 


var getknow=prompt("Do you want to cheack the schedule? Type the week name");


if ( getknow == saturday) {

alert(saturday);

} else if (getknow == sunday ) {

alert(sunday); 
} else if (getknow == monday) {

alert(monday); 

} else if (getknow == tuesday) {

alert(tuesday);

}
```

everything is working now without theese lines of codes

```
var getknow=prompt("Do you want to cheack the schedule? Type the week name");

if ( getknow == saturday) {

alert(saturday);

} else if ( getknow == sunday ) {

alert(sunday); 

} else if ( getknow == monday ) {

alert(monday); 

} else if ( getknow == tuesday ) {

alert(tuesday);

}
```

Comment: What is not working?  What do you expect to happen?  What really happens?

Comment: nothing is happening here. i expect to happen exactly what i wrote in the code @RocketHazmat

Comment: Do you see any errors in your console (`Ctrl`+`Shift`+`J` in *most* browsers)?

Comment: yes but i cant understand the problem

Comment: It's helpful if you post the errors that you get, for future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you had some errors, but keep learning and with time you won't make many mistakes. Read the comments below, also check this code out, it should work fine.

I will list the errors below. The first one was:

```
var monday=prompt("var getknow=prompt(""What will you do in monday?");
```

Then I saw that you declared the same variables twice, which you don't need to do:

```
var sunday=prompt("What will you do in sunday?");
var tuesday=prompt("What will you do in tuesday?");
var sunday=prompt("What will you do in sunday?");
```

Later on you were comparing the user's answer with a variable, it should have been a string:

```
    if ( getknow == saturday) {

alert(saturday);

} else if (getknow == sunday ) {

alert(sunday); 
} else if (getknow == monday) {

alert(monday); 

} else if (getknow == tuesday) {

alert(tuesday);

}
```

This code should work:

```
var plan = prompt("Hello , Made a week plan. Type the week name to add a event").toLowerCase(),
    week = ["saturday" , "sunday" , "monday" , "tuesday"],
    saturday,
    sunday,
    monday,
    tuesday;

if( plan === "saturday" ) {

    saturday = prompt("What will you do in saturday?");

} 

else if ( plan === "sunday") {

    sunday = prompt("What will you do in sunday?");

} 

else if (plan === "monday") {
    //ERROR var monday=prompt("var getknow=prompt(""What will you do in monday?");
    monday = prompt("What will you do in monday?");

} 

else if (plan === "tuesday" ) {

    tuesday = prompt("What will you do in tuesday?");

} 


var getknow = prompt("Do you want to cheack the schedule? Type the week name");

// Also here, the prompt will be a sting not a variable
if ( getknow === "saturday") {

alert(saturday);

} 

else if (getknow === "sunday" ) {

alert(sunday); 
} 

else if (getknow === "monday") {

alert(monday); 

} 

else if (getknow === "tuesday") {

alert(tuesday);
}
```

Comment: No problem, don't worry about your mistakes, everyone has made such at the beginning. With time and practice you will get used to the language. Success on your way with JavaScript! PS. Most important thing while learning a new language is to keep going, over a month or so you will come back here and tell me that I was right!

Answer (score 1):

This line is definitly a problem. There are two " symbol inside a string. Probably you copied something in it you didn't want to copy.

```
var monday=prompt("var getknow=prompt(""What will you do in monday?");
```

Comment: but the *getknow* variable is not working :(

Comment: in my opinion, it is very important when scripting javascript to use a debugger such as firebug for firefox or something equivalent for other browser. Then you can inspect your variables during runtime. You must learn that, it is worth it. Good fun!